# Oracle APEX - Enabling Persistent Authentication Breaks Deep Linking

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I am using Oracle APEX 23.1.

I created an app, then enabled PWA after I created it.  I have enabled persistent authentication on the instance and in the application.

But now, deep linking isnt working.  All deep links take me to the Home page (authenticated, so peristent authentication is working).

So I can only have deep linking working when I disable persistent authentication apparently, unless I am missing some setting.

If I log on and press "Rememeber me" to enable persistent authentication, persistent authentication works but deep linking fails.

If I log out and then log in again and DONT press "Remember me",  when I use a deep link, I am asked to authenticate and then am taking to the correct deep link location.